# After creating a NativeScript Typescript application, I tried running it using the command "ns run android" it doesnt run and i get the output

Tags: android-studio, nativescript

After creating a NativeScript Typescript application, I tried running it using the command `ns run android` I get this output and does not run.

- The `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
  To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory.
- WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
  For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
  To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
  Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
  its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements
- WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
  You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
  in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK
  and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements
- Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later.
  Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions.
- No compatible version of the Android SDK Build-tools are installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=32'.
  Install the required build-tools through Android Studio. In case you already have them installed, make sure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors and warnings says that you haven't Android SDK and adb which one is included in the Android SDK Platform-Tools package.

First of all, you need to read this doc and complete steps in it - https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html. This documentation has everything you need, based on your operating system and the operating system you want to develop the application for.

If you already install everything docs says, check your path environment for `ANDROID_HOME` and `adb` variables presence, if not, add them. For example, my path (on MacOS) contains following lines:

```
/Users/sixhellstations/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/sixhellstations/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/sixhellstations/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/sixhellstations/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```